# python - call class variable from another class

Tags: python, pyside

I'm working out classes and trying to get to work setCentralWidget() in my PySide GUI.
I've got a MainWindow, and two widgets: mainWidget and searchWidget, which one I want to show up after the searchButton is clicked.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        mainWidget = MainWidget()

        self.resize(300,500)
        self.statusBar()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Elo Elo')
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)   # <---- setting centralWidget first time
        self.setWindowTitle('StartApp Welcome')
```

and the searchWidget()

```
class SearchWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=MainWindow):

        super(SearchWidget,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):       

        backButton = QPushButton('GoBack', self)
        backButton.clicked.connect(self.goBack)

    def goBack(self):

        self.parent().setCentralWidget(self.parent().mainWidget)  # <--- error line
```

error

```
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'mainWidget'
```

I can't figure out, how to get to the MainWidget() instance 'mainWidget'. Could You help me somehow? Thanks

Comment: i could create new instance of MainWidget in the last class, but its silly I think. I would that the first instance still exist, and refer to it, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in this line:

```
self.parent().setCentralWidget(self.parent().mainWidget)
```

you attempt to access the variable `mainWidget` as if it were an *attribute* of `MainWindow`- it is not (at the moment it is just a local variable). This is because you do not initialize it as `self.mainWidget`, which you must do to get it to work like you want it to.

```
self.mainwidget = MainWidget()
```

Comment: Well I tried it this way, but I get something this time I get:
    self.parent().setCentralWidget(self.parent().mainWidget)
    RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (MainWidget) already deleted[code]

Comment: @user4175226 So ask a question about that; that is a separate issue. I have fixed the issue that you gave in the question.